# Can I pass an OnTextChanged event a specific GridViewRow for faster processing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**Question**:  How can I modify either the `UpdateColumns()` method (below) or the `OnTextChanged` event call to only use the row that is firing the event??

Right now, I'm updating GridView cell values by calling a `UpdateColumns()` method using the `OnTextChanged` event as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="35px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox OnTextChanged="UpdateColumns" ID="txtJan" CssClass="row"
        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Text='<%# Eval("Jan","{0:#0}") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Jan
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJan" CssClass="row" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Below is the `UpdateColumns()` method that the `OnTextChanged` event fires.  It loops through each row in the table and does the calculations.  There are 15 columns in my GridView, and 10 rows, so the operation takes ~1 second to complete.  How can I modify my method to only look at the row that it's called from?  Essentially, I just want the operation to perform faster, and not do useless calculations.

```
Protected Sub UpdateColumns(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim errors As New StringBuilder

    Try
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvBuildingBlocks.Rows

            _tjan = CType(row.FindControl("txtJan"), TextBox)
            _tfeb = CType(row.FindControl("txtFeb"), TextBox)
            _tmar = CType(row.FindControl("txtMar"), TextBox)
            _tapr = CType(row.FindControl("txtApr"), TextBox)
            _tmay = CType(row.FindControl("txtMay"), TextBox)
            _tjun = CType(row.FindControl("txtJun"), TextBox)
            _tjul = CType(row.FindControl("txtJul"), TextBox)
            _taug = CType(row.FindControl("txtAug"), TextBox)
            _tsep = CType(row.FindControl("txtSep"), TextBox)
            _toct = CType(row.FindControl("txtOct"), TextBox)
            _tnov = CType(row.FindControl("txtNov"), TextBox)
            _tdec = CType(row.FindControl("txtDec"), TextBox)
            _tq1 = CType(row.FindControl("txtQ1"), TextBox)
            _tq2 = CType(row.FindControl("txtQ2"), TextBox)
            _tq3 = CType(row.FindControl("txtQ3"), TextBox)
            _tq4 = CType(row.FindControl("txtQ4"), TextBox)
            _th1 = CType(row.FindControl("txtH1"), TextBox)
            _th2 = CType(row.FindControl("txtH2"), TextBox)
            _tt = CType(row.FindControl("txtYear"), TextBox)

            If IsNumeric(_tjan.Text) And IsNumeric(_tfeb.Text) _
            And IsNumeric(_tmar.Text) And IsNumeric(_tapr.Text) _
            And IsNumeric(_tmay.Text) And IsNumeric(_tjun.Text) _
            And IsNumeric(_tjul.Text) And IsNumeric(_taug.Text) _
            And IsNumeric(_tsep.Text) And IsNumeric(_toct.Text) _
            And IsNumeric(_tnov.Text) And IsNumeric(_tdec.Text) Then
                _bbjan = Decimal.Parse(_tjan.Text)
                _bbfeb = Decimal.Parse(_tfeb.Text)
                _bbmar = Decimal.Parse(_tmar.Text)
                _bbapr = Decimal.Parse(_tapr.Text)
                _bbmay = Decimal.Parse(_tmay.Text)
                _bbjun = Decimal.Parse(_tjun.Text)
                _bbjul = Decimal.Parse(_tjul.Text)
                _bbaug = Decimal.Parse(_taug.Text)
                _bbsep = Decimal.Parse(_tsep.Text)
                _bboct = Decimal.Parse(_toct.Text)
                _bbnov = Decimal.Parse(_tnov.Text)
                _bbdec = Decimal.Parse(_tdec.Text)
                _bbq1 = _bbjan + _bbfeb + _bbmar
                _bbq2 = _bbapr + _bbmay + _bbjun
                _bbq3 = _bbjul + _bbaug + _bbsep
                _bbq4 = _bboct + _bbnov + _bbdec
                _bbh1 = _bbq1 + _bbq2
                _bbh2 = _bbq3 + _bbq4
                _bbtt = _bbh1 + _bbh2

                _tq1.Text = _bbq1.ToString()
                _tq2.Text = _bbq2.ToString()
                _tq3.Text = _bbq3.ToString()
                _tq4.Text = _bbq4.ToString()
                _th1.Text = _bbh1.ToString()
                _th2.Text = _bbh2.ToString()
                _tt.Text = _bbtt.ToString()

                _totalJan += _bbjan
                _totalFeb += _bbfeb
                _totalMar += _bbmar
                _totalApr += _bbapr
                _totalMay += _bbmay
                _totalJun += _bbjun
                _totalJul += _bbjul
                _totalAug += _bbaug
                _totalSep += _bbsep
                _totalOct += _bboct
                _totalNov += _bbnov
                _totalDec += _bbdec
                _totalQ1 += _bbq1
                _totalQ2 += _bbq2
                _totalQ3 += _bbq3
                _totalQ4 += _bbq4
                _totalH1 += _bbh1
                _totalH2 += _bbh2
                _totalT += _bbtt
            Else
                errors.Append("Error!  Input string must be numeric.  Please correct error(s).")
            End If
        Next

        If errors.Length > 0 Then
            'gvBuildingBlocks.DataSource = CType(Session("buildingBlocks"), DataTable)
            'gvBuildingBlocks.DataBind()
            ShowMessage(errors.ToString)
        End If

        _tjan = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtJan"), TextBox)
        _tfeb = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFeb"), TextBox)
        _tmar = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMar"), TextBox)
        _tapr = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtApr"), TextBox)
        _tmay = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMay"), TextBox)
        _tjun = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtJun"), TextBox)
        _tjul = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtJul"), TextBox)
        _taug = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAug"), TextBox)
        _tsep = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSep"), TextBox)
        _toct = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOct"), TextBox)
        _tnov = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNov"), TextBox)
        _tdec = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDec"), TextBox)
        _tq1 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQ1"), TextBox)
        _tq2 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQ2"), TextBox)
        _tq3 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQ3"), TextBox)
        _tq4 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQ4"), TextBox)
        _th1 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtH1"), TextBox)
        _th2 = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtH2"), TextBox)
        _tt = CType(gvBuildingBlocks.FooterRow.FindControl("txtYear"), TextBox)

        _tjan.Text = _totalJan.ToString()
        _tfeb.Text = _totalFeb.ToString()
        _tmar.Text = _totalMar.ToString()
        _tapr.Text = _totalApr.ToString()
        _tmay.Text = _totalMay.ToString()
        _tjun.Text = _totalJun.ToString()
        _tjul.Text = _totalJul.ToString()
        _taug.Text = _totalAug.ToString()
        _tsep.Text = _totalSep.ToString()
        _toct.Text = _totalOct.ToString()
        _tnov.Text = _totalNov.ToString()
        _tdec.Text = _totalDec.ToString()
        _tq1.Text = _totalQ1.ToString()
        _tq2.Text = _totalQ2.ToString()
        _tq3.Text = _totalQ3.ToString()
        _tq4.Text = _totalQ4.ToString()
        _th1.Text = _totalH1.ToString()
        _th2.Text = _totalH2.ToString()
        _tt.Text = _totalT.ToString()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowError("Exception: ", ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sender" argument should contain the control that fired the event.  You should be able to figure out what has changed based on your sender, and only redo calculations for what's changed.

Comment: I assumed that `sender` or `e` would hold some clues.  I just thought that the options IntelliSense offered under `sender` weren't very useful.  Perhaps I'm wrong?  IntelliSense lists `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()`, `ReferenceEquals()`, and `ToString()`.  I'll do some more investigating.  Thank you.

Comment: sender is an object.  If you cast it to the right type, you'll be able to get any info you need out of it.  For instance, if the sender is an ASP.NET Textbox, you can cast sender to a TextBox type and then you can access the ID or Text properties to determine which text box is the one that triggered the event.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for your help.  I didn't know much about the event parameters until now.